# Create dataframe from str without using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, aws-lambda

Have a `str` in python like this: `'2,9,3,5,0,4,0,0,0'`

Transforming it to `DataFrame` using `Pandas` and `split()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(',') for x in my_string.split('\n')])
```

Developing `Lambda` on `Aws` and there are some missing libraries at the moment including Pandas, is it possible to get the `DataFrame` without using `Pandas`?

Many thanks!

Comment: What does "DataFrame" mean if you don't have pandas?

Comment: array of arrays

Comment: What is wrong with `[x.split(',') for x in my_string.split('\n')]`?

Comment: Lambdas have numpy layers available, so you can work directly in numpy. But be aware: A `DataFrame()` is a specific object to pandas, you will not be operating on a dataframe you'll be working on lists of lists or arrays. Just to help with terminology as you search for solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're putting into pandas is a list comprehension.

```
[x.split(',') for x in my_string.split('\n')]
```

That's pure python code, and it returns the list of lists that you're looking for. Pandas takes that list of lists and makes it into a pandas specific object called a dataframe, but if you just want a list of lists, it's right there in the list comprehension itself.

```
listoflists = [x.split(',') for x in my_string.split('\n')]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about `[x.split(',') for x in my_string.split('\n')]`